# namedtuple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on my project but I am getting error on calling `namedtuple()` function with error

```
TypeError: namedtuple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

I don't know why is it happening please guide me
 here is my function call

```
namedtuple('PartPair', ['score', 'part_idx1', 'part_idx2', 'idx1', 'idx2', 'coord1', 'coord2', 'score1', 'score2'],
                      verbose=False)
```

Please help me regarding this issue

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me.  You are calling `namedtuple()` with an unexpected keyword argument `'verbose'`.  To fix this problem remove `verbose=False` from the function call.

Comment: Raymond explains this - if we don't say nice things about features, they can some day disappear: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw (I don't remember the exact time)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What version of python are you using?

Since python3.7 verbose argument was removed.

For more information follow this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields).

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> Changed in version 3.7: Remove the verbose parameter and the _source attribute.